# How to use fullpage.js with ngFor

Tags: angular, fullpage.js

I seem to be forced to add a fake section to activate the rest of the ngFor loop with ngx-fullpage (see line "Do I need this"). I don't understand why, I've tried removing specific classes, but nothing seems to help.

```
 <div mnFullpage [mnFullpageNavigation]="true"
          [mnFullpageSlidesNavPosition]="false">
    <div id="section0" class="section fp-section fp-table"></div> <!-- Do I need this-->

    <div [attr.id]="'section' + i " class="section fp-section fp-table"
             *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
            <h2> {{item.name}}</h2>
           <span>
            <img
             [src]="item.imagePath"
             alt="{{item.name}}"
             class="img-responsive">
           </span>
         </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```